# Incorrectly set up core.editor Git

Tags: git, git-config

I downloaded Git and added "sublimetext3" as `core.editor` value instead of "subl -n -w".  I now added "subl -n -w" as `core.editor` value, but `core.editor` value "sublimetext3" is also there when I type `git config --list`

Also, I can't open .md file in terminal.  I type `Contributors.md` and get the response

```
-bash: Contributors.md: command not found.
```

When I try to `git config --edit` I get the following:

```
error: cannot run sublimetext3: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'sublimetext3'.
```

Comment: Try unsetting the field multiple times `git config --unset "core.editor"`. That should reset it to `vi`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your local and global configs, and compare :

```
git config --local --list

git config --global --list
```

You might have set it at one level with `subl` but being overridden by the other setting with `sublimetext3`

---

Then if so, to set it right, explicitly give the level of config when setting the property :

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
# and/or
git config --local core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

(I didn't mention `--system`, `--worktree` or `--file` which exist too, because I guess it's less likely that you would have changed that without knowing, but might be worth checking, see all details [here in the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_description))

Comment: Thanks, I ended up resolving the issue by deleting the repository and doing the process over again.  I did read through the documentation and it was helpful as was your fix.  Had I seen this prior to deleting the repository I believe it would've worked.